# animating to certain height based on if a div has a certain class

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I have a div that I'd like to animate to 3 different heights depending on the click element.  I had wanted to do it with classes, so if one of the clicked elements, a div named d_foxboro is clicked and it has a class of height_one the location_slider is aniamted to the first height, if another div is clicked, d_main and it has a class of height_two then location_slider is animated to teh second height, and so on.

```
$( "#d_Foxboro" ).click(function(){
$( "#location_slider" ).animate({
"height": 500
}, 450 );
});
```

Comment: You are using an ID as selector for adding click event handler so your statement "depending on if the clicked element has a certain class" doesn't make sense to me as ID must be unique for each element on page. Could you clarify your question?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$( "#d_Foxboro" ).click(function(){
    var height = 0;
    if($(this).hasClass('class1')){ 
       height = 400; 
   } else if($(this).hasClass('class2')){ 
       height = 500; 
   } else if($(this).hasClass('class3')){ 
       height = 600; 
   }

   $( "#location_slider" ).animate({
       "height": height
   }, 450 );

});
```

Basically, use hasClass to see which class your element has, then set the variable which contains your height depending on the class

Comment: how would you add the 3rd class option into that?

Comment: Simply add another else if, have edited my code accordingly, all you need to do now is to change 'class1', 'class2' and 'class3' with your own classes and the height with your own values

Answer (score 0):

I personally like to use the `.on()` method for binding events because it allows me to easily change it if the element is dynamically added to the DOM.

```
$( "#d_Foxboro" ).on("click", function(){
    var height = 0;
    if ($(this).hasClass() == "someClass"){
        height = 100;
    }
    else
    {
        height = 200;           
     }
    $( "#location_slider" ).animate({
         "height": height
       }, 450 );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When clicked check the class then set a height variable based of that

```
$( "#d_Foxboro" ).click(function(){
  // Default height
  var h = 0; // Set to a default number
  // Class of clicked item
  var h_class = $(this).attr('class');

  // Check class and set height based of which class
  if(h_class == "something") {
    h = 500;
  } else if(h_class == "something else") {
    h = 400
  }

  $( "#location_slider" ).animate({
    "height": h
  }, 450 );

});
```

Comment: Thats not a correct answer as an element can get more than just one class. Correct answer is to use hasClass() or if($(this).attr('class').indexOf("something")!=-1)